# element id on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript to get the element's id on mouse over. But I am not getting it.
As per my code it is showing null.

My code is:

```
function getid() {
  var e = document.getElementById(this);
  alert(e);
}
```

and I am calling the function on:

```
<input 
  style="margin: 8px 4px 4px 4px; width:142px; height:117px;"
  type="image" 
  id="img" 
  src="images2.jpg" 
  onmouseover="getid();" 
  onmouseout="outmouse();" 
/>
```

How can I get the elements id on mouse over?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

check this

```js
function getid(obj) {
  alert(obj.id);
}
```

```html
<input style="margin: 8px 4px 4px; width:142px; height:117px;" type="image" id="img" src="images2.jpg" onmouseover="getid(this);" />
```

Answer (score 7):

The value of intrinsic event attributes is the function *body*. What you have is the same as:

```
onmouseover = function () {
    getid();
}
```

When you call a function without an object, it is the same as `window.thefunction()`. So you are calling `window.getid()` so `this` (inside the getid function) is the window object.

If you really want to use intrinsic event attributes (hint: [don't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)), then you have to be explicit about what `this` is.

```
onmouseover="getid.call(this)"
```

However, then:

```
var e = document.getElementById(this);
```

… is nonsense because `this` is the element and not the element's id.

You could get the id property from `this`, and use that to look up the element, but that would be silly as you can simply:

```
var e = this;
```

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery:

```
$(input).mouseover(function()
{
   var showID = $(this).attr("ID");
   alert(showID);
});
```