# How do I merge these similar functions into one

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

I've been trying to wrap my head around Javascript, been searching for a way to make this into one function that only affects the DOM element (which i also created with javascript through createElement) that is currently being hovered. I tried the .target and currentTarget stuff, didn work. If anyone could do as much as point me in the right direction I'd be eternally grateful!

```
/* This first function is the experimental one, I tried this but to no avail */
function displayTooltip1(tt) {
    var x = tt.currentTarget;
    x.style.cssText = "width: 100px; height: 100px; display: inline-block; margin: 0;1.5px 0 1.5px; overflow: visible;"
}

function displayTooltip2() {
    document.getElementById('image2').style.cssText = "width: 100px; height: 100px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 1.5px 0 1.5px; overflow: visible;";
}

function displayTooltip3() {
    document.getElementById('image3').style.cssText = "width: 100px; height: 100px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 1.5px 0 1.5px; overflow: visible;";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the id of the component and grab the component by that id.

use as follow:

```
function displayTooltip(componentId) {
    document.getElementById(componentId).style.cssText = "width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 1.5px 0 1.5px; overflow: visible;";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, however, forgive me for asking this: how would I make this dynamical? What would I put instead of 'componentId'? Since there are 8 different ID's.

Comment: at the time of calling the function specify the id of the target. e.g. hover target

Comment: you can specify the function onmouse over at the time of creating dynamic elements. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186065/element-id-on-mouse-over

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, all your functions do the same things, but with different elements, so you can make a function, which will accept an ID of element and make style changes with that element:

```
function displayTooltip(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.cssText = "width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 1.5px 0 1.5px; overflow: visible;";
}

displayTooltip(tt);
displayTooltip('image2');
displayTooltip('image3');
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for bothering! Second, how would I make it recognize which one is activating the function? I.e. which parameter value to choose?

Comment: It's simple, you need to use ID of element, which style you wanna change

Comment: Working like a charm!