# If in function according to id

Tags: javascript, html

I want `playSound()` function to do its job according to the `id` of the chosen (hovered) image.
Nothing I tried has worked even a bit, so I need full help on this one.

code:

```js
var sound1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
var sound2 = document.getElementById("audio2");

function playSound() {
  //if hovered image has id="x", do this
  sound1.play();

  //if hovered image has id="y", do this
  sound2.play();
}
```

```html
<a href="Okokoska.html"><img src="Pkokoska.jpg" id="x" onmouseover="playSound()" onmouseout="stop()"></a>
<a href="Okonj.html"><img src="Pkonj.jpg" id="y" onmouseover="playSound()" onmouseout="stop()"></a>

<audio id="audio1"><source src="Zkokoska.wav"></audio>
<audio id="audio2"><source src="Zkrava.wav"></audio>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [element id on mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186065/element-id-on-mouse-over)

Comment: your HTML is wrong: your missing type="audio/wav" on your source

Comment: @JensIngels, I removed it as it works without it as well

Comment: @derpirscher Maybe somebody would get something out of it... I didn't see an answer there, but thanks

Comment: Well, the accepted answer to the referenced question shows how to get the id of the element that raised the event. and once you know the id, you know which sound you have to play. It's more or less the same, as the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `this` into `onmouseover="playSound(this)"`, that will pass a hovered element.

Then you catch it in function:

```
function playSound(e) {
```

and use to save the id, then just make if statement.

```
let id = e.id;
```

```js
var sound1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
var sound2 = document.getElementById("audio2");

function playSound(e) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(e.id);
  let id = e.id;

  if (id === "x") {
    //if hovered image has id="x", do this
    sound1.play();
     console.log("Playing sound x");
  } else if (id === "y") {
    //if hovered image has id="y", do this
    sound2.play();
    console.log("Playing sound y");
  }

}
```

```html
<a href="Okokoska.html"><img src="Pkokoska.jpg" id="x" onmouseover="playSound(this)" onmouseout="stop()"></a>
<a href="Okonj.html"><img src="Pkonj.jpg" id="y" onmouseover="playSound(this)" onmouseout="stop()"></a>

<audio id="audio1"><source src="Zkokoska.wav"></audio>
<audio id="audio2"><source src="Zkrava.wav"></audio>
```

Comment: It works perfectly and it's exactly what I needed! Hvala :)

Comment: @Sas Oh, nema na čemu ;)  I drugi puta

Comment: One tip, name your parameter 'target' instead of 'e'. Just a clarity tip but it does help to separate types of functions in larger projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use inline JavaScript to know much more should not use it just se [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002690/why-inline-javascript-is-bad) so due to the above just use an [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or use listener assignment like `id.onclick = function(){}...`
here is an

### example

```js
var sound1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
var sound2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var y = document.getElementById("y");

x.onmouseover = () => {
  sound1.play();
}
x.onmouseout = () => {
  sound1.pause();
}
y.onmouseover = () => {
  sound2.play();
}
y.onmouseout = () => {
  sound2.pause();
}
```

```html
<a href="Okokoska.html"><img src="Pkokoska.jpg"></a>
<a href="Okonj.html"><img src="Pkonj.jpg" id="y"></a>

<audio id="audio1"><source src="Zkokoska.wav"></audio>
<audio id="audio2"><source src="Zkrava.wav"></audio>
```

Or you can see the bellow example too hope you'll find it helpful

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var audio = document.getElementById("player");

button.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  audio.play();
  button.innerHTML = "Play";
});
button.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  audio.pause();
  button.innerHTML = "Pause";
});
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #00ffff;
  color: blue;
  padding: 13px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="button">Play</button>
</div>

<audio id="player">
  <source src='http://hi5.1980s.fm/;' type='audio/mpeg'/>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass **event** as parameter in the **playSound** function bound to **img** tag with **onclick** and access it in your logic to verify Id.

**HTML**

```
<a href="Okokoska.html"><img src="Pkokoska.jpg" id="x" onmouseover="playSound(event)" onmouseout="stop()"></a>
<a href="Okonj.html"><img src="Pkonj.jpg" id="y" onmouseover="playSound(event)" onmouseout="stop()"></a>

<audio id="audio1"><source src="Zkokoska.wav"></audio>
<audio id="audio2"><source src="Zkrava.wav"></audio>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var sound1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
var sound2 = document.getElementById("audio2");

function playSound(event) {
  if(event.target.id == "x"){
    sound1.play(); 
  }else if(event.target.id == "y"){
    sound2.play();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am long not into script, but have you tried this (i didn’t tried)?

```
function playSound(){
document.getElementById("x").addEventListener("click", function(){ document.getElementById("audio1").play()[0]; });
document.getElementById("y").addEventListener("click", function(){ document.getElementById("audio2").play()[0]; });
}
```